# Detect if iPhone has moved

Tags: ios, iphone, core-motion

I'm trying to detect if an iPhone was moved (even a slight movement), and then if the device was moved, i want the iPhone to play a sound.

Im new to IOS programming, and I've looked through a bunch of apple documentations, and i found that i must use `CoreMotion` . But I'm not sure how to implement it, to what id like to do in my app.

I've also searched on google for some help (e.g. NSHipster...), but i couldn't fine anything that meets my needs.

can anyone assist?

Thank you.

Comment: To your question: You need to learn how to play sounds, and how to monitor the accelerometer. Try learning one thing at a time. And, find a tutorial somewhere that does either of them, and follow it.

Comment: @jpaugh i know how to play sounds, among a lot of other things in IOS. I've looked up a lot of tutorials, but i couldn't find anything to what i want to do, regarding detecting motion.

Comment: My comments were not constructive, and ultimately pointless. I have deleted them. My apologies to you

Comment: Haha it's ok, but I still don't know how to detect the motion @jpaugh

Comment: A lot of different apps use it, so I'm assuming there is documentation for it... You'll probably get refined answers (here) once you get "stuck" trying to use it, and then have a more specific question. (And, I've never worked with iOS, so I can't help.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to detect an iPhone shake. Apple has an article on the subject:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW2

Comment: Ive tried that already, but I'm not trying to detect a shake, I'm trying to detect the slightest movement.

Comment: A slight movement IS a shake. There is no standard for "slight movements".

Comment: Its possible but using CoreMotion with the magnetometer, accelerometer, and the gyroscope. i just don't know how to implement it.  @vaiden

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need the motion accelerometer in `CMMotionManager`.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMMotionManager/accelerometerData

Comment: Yes. But I'm new to programming and i don't know how to implement that code to detect the slightest movement, and play a sound.